# How to add tearDown Thread Group class in java code?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to develop a java application which uses jmeter's maven library `artifactId: ApacheJMeter_http` to load test.

My application does distributed remote tests, and i want to execute some java code after the test finishes execution. Upon reviewing the JMeter docs, I found out that `tearDown Thread Group` can do the job. In the JMeter GUI, you can simply add this type of Thread Group, but I can't find the equivalent java class in JMeter's library.

Moreover, I am still not sure how to execute java code even after i manage to add this thread group to my test tree.

**EDIT:**

Found the answer to part 1 of my question. tearDown Thread Groups are named `PostThreadGroup` by jmeter.

Still not sure how to execute java code using a PostThreadGroup. Basically I want to call a hook after the execution of a test.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine the class for this or that JMeter test component:

1. Open [logger panel](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) by clicking yellow triangle with exclamation sign in the top-right corner of JMeter GUI
   [image]
2. Having highlighted the test component choose `Help -> What's this node`
3. The element class and GUI class will be displayed in the jmeter.log

   [image]

The class you need is [PostThreadGroup](https://PostThreadGroup), see the JavaDoc for all possible methods/fields/whatever.

More information: [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: Thanks! Any clue how to execute a java hook after a test plan has completed execution?